# Launcher Activity Issue Android

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, launcher

I created a splash screen for my android application. In my AndroidManifest I set the SplashScreen Activity as Launcher and action as MAIN. After that I changed the HomeActivity's intentfilter. 
Here is my android manifest file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityHome"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITHOME" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Receivers.NetworkReceiver"></receiver>


    </application>
```

I have both these activities inside the default package. Now, when I try to test the application in device, I get the following error:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.sdz.myapp/com.sdz.myapp.SplashScreenActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.sdz.myapp/.SplashScreenActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.sdz.myapp/com.sdz.myapp.SplashScreenActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

This is how my project structure looks like:

```
src
-com.sdz.myapp
----ActivityHome
----SplashScreenActivity
```

I restarted android studio but still the error is there. I dont know what is causing this.

Comment: Post your complete AndroidManifest.xml file here

Comment: Are you getting any warning at compile-time?

Comment: What is your package defined in AndoridManifest.xml?

Comment: _com.sdz.myapp_ I have done all the checks before posting a question here.

Comment: As soon as I make ActivityHome the launcher activity, the error vanishes.

Comment: Are you using android studio or eclipse ?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Ok this is just an idea but please check and be sure your `applicationId` value equal to `com.sdz.myapp` on your **build.gradle** file

Comment: It is same as earlier i.e 'com.sdz.myapp'. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well. I actually had to uninstall the apk from the device before it would work... which was really odd as the app wasn't showing up on my list of apps on the phone.

Here's what I did:

1. Opened up command line
2. Ran 'adb devices' to make sure my device was connected
3. ran 'adb uninstall ' Replace  with "com.whatever.blah"
4. You should see a message saying it uninstall successfully
5. Try installing from Android Studio again and it should work

I have no idea how it gets in this weird state. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Please change your `android:name` value at your activity tag with full name and first **clean project** . After that try to run your application again

```
<activity android:name="com.sdz.myapp.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: Tried the same without clean up. Trying this with a clean up now

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue occasionally. The solution was to build the APK (menu "Build > Build APK") and install it manually in the phone. After that the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above plus even delete the build folder and still did not work. The solution for me was: On your Android Studio go to File->Sync Project with Gradle Files